# Turn a string of multiple Longitude and Latitudes into 2 arrays (one for Longitude, one for Latitude)

Tags: php, arrays, latitude-longitude

I will be passing strings of Longitude & Latitude values of a polygon like this below.

```
[ [ 51.11041991029261, -2.274169921875 ], [ 51.08282186160978, -3.460693359375 ], [ 50.443513052458044, -3.570556640625 ], [ 50.443513052458044, -1.966552734375 ] ]
```

I need to take that string and turn it into 2 arrays. 1 with just the Longitude values (the values to the left of the []'s) and an array of the Latitude (the value to the right of the []'s) - or whichever way around I always get them mixed up.

I've played around with explode and a couple other PHP functions but I'm having no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like JSON, so...

```
$json = <<<JSON
[ [ 51.11041991029261, -2.274169921875 ], [ 51.08282186160978, -3.460693359375 ], [ 50.443513052458044, -3.570556640625 ], [ 50.443513052458044, -1.966552734375 ] ]
JSON;

$coords = json_decode($json, true);
$lats   = array_map(function (array $coord) { return $coord[0]; }, $coords);
$lons   = array_map(function (array $coord) { return $coord[1]; }, $coords);
```

In PHP 5.5+:

```
$lats = array_column($coords, 0);
$lons = array_column($coords, 1);
```

Comment: Sorry didn't notice as was passing it from a form on a previous page. Works perfectly, thanks for the quick response!